# Create google GCM testing app in emulator and get registration id using PHP

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to create a testing app which will run at emulator and the GCM server will use PHP.

I'm looking the code how it pushes the message to target device, the following code I downloaded somewhere:

```
<?php    
  $json = array();    
  $regId = $_GET["regID"];
  $msg = $_GET["msg"];
  if (isset($regId) && isset($msg)) {
      require_once("GCM.php");

      $message = array("message" => $msg);
      $regId = explode(",", $regId);
      $result = gcm_push_notification($regId, $message);

      $success_code = json_decode($result,true)["success"];
      if($success_code > 0){
    //echo $result; //
    echo $success_code."/".count($regId); //
      }else{
    echo "error";
      }
  } else {
      echo "error";
  }
?>
```

The code every time will need "registration id"s to send a message:

- I am wondering how can I get all registration ids every time before
  sending a message?
- And if I create a simple app which will run at emulator only, will it generate a registration id? How do I get that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a database and store all the registration id's in the server. And emulators can generate GCM ID. Make sure you set your emulator target to Google API.
If your emulator is running Android 4.0 and below, add an Google account to your emulator.

Comment: is there any sample source i can get all reg id from google server?

Comment: for android client side, i use https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start this example, i had done as the picture show, but how to i run the command (./gradlew run -Pargs="<message>")? where can i do that?

Comment: You said i could create database and store all the registration id's, but how can i get them?

Comment: Have a module in your app which sends the GCM device token (registration id) to your server and store them in a database on your server. Registration ID will be generated for a unique device installation which you can manage on your server to send push notifications.